# Django models question: does not return model string representation name

Tags: django, string, unicode, django-models

Hello I seem to have a trouble with my models. Seems to me that I cannot name a string representation name. In python shell, I get an Payment object instead.

```
[<Payment: Payment object>, <Payment: Payment object>]
```

Here is my models. It should be more simpler if I could remove where I defined line_total but as you already know, it is not so simple to edit the models once you have generated the tables.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    payment_terms = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

    def line_total():
        unit_price -= discount 
        return line_total

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.line_total
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code that you should fix: `unit_price` nor `line_total` are declared in `line_total()` method. Also, `line_total` is a class method and will take a `self` argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, look like I am going to keep it this way. I have removed line_total field because 1st reason, I do not really need it & 2nd reason is that somehow, there was no column that was created for accounts_payment.line_total. So in my mysql database. I have also now made it so it returns a unit_price rather than an object. Anyway thaks for everyone for helping me anyway.

Comment: Why did you accept your own answer as the best answer? It isn't an answer at all, frankly. You've left errors in your code that others pointed out in the comments. Like the overlapping field name and method name for line_total. So your answer should not be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation on `__unicode__()` is incorrect. It should be at the same level as `line_total()`.

Comment: what sort of changes would I need to make?

Comment: You would need to indent it to the same level as `line_total()`.

Comment: I seem to be getting a lot of these errors while trying to make that unicode indent to the same line "Caught OperationalError while rendering: (1054, "Unknown column 'accounts_payment.line_total' in 'field list'")"

Comment: That's because it's not a field; it's a method.

Comment: Then you haven't got that field in your table. Since you don't seem to want it anyway, delete the field definition.

Answer (score 0):

When your model is printed within a list, it's not `__unicode__` method that is called but `__repr__` (that you can also implement with usually a simpler output than `__unicode__`)

Comment: True, but the default `__repr__` on a Django model calls `__unicode__`, so it's usually easiest to just define that.

Comment: Well not exactly according to: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py#L360.